# Defining root URL in Simfony2

Tags: symfony, webserver, friendly-url

Let's say I have a Symfony webapp and it is in a subfolder of my webroot

```
path/to/root/<subfolder>/Symfony/
```

So if I would want to call my page I have to enter

```
http://host.tld/<subfolder>/Symfony/web
```

But as you can imagine I would like everyone just to call

```
http://www.host.tld/
```

I know that I can use the webserver's settings (e.g. define root directory, set alias etc.). Thus I derive two questions:

1. Where do I tell Symfony that this is the base of all to be created links? And
2. Does Symfony provide a native function or configuration, where I can set this up without having to change my webserver's configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dedicated server :**

If you are on a dedicated debian server (with apache), you probably know what is a vhost.

You need to create a Vhost and point the domain to the web folder of the Symfony project to encapsulate users :

nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/host.tld :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/sybio/www/mywebsite/Symfony/web

    <Directory "/home/sybio/www/mywebsite/Symfony/web">
        DirectoryIndex app.php
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then test apache configuration :

```
apache2ctl configtest
```

If no error restart :

```
apache2ctl restart
```

That's it !

**Shared hosting :**

In many hosters, like OVH, you can configurate the destination folder (web dir) thanks to admin panel !
If you can't, this is easy :

1) add Symfony structure at the root dir of your shared hosting

2) Rename the web/ dir by the one used by your hoster (oftently "www" or "public")

3) Override Sf configuration to say "web" dir is now named "www" : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the Symfony folder and all it's contents to someplace else such as `/home/work/Symfony`
2. Copy `Symfony/web/.htaccess` and `app.php` to `http://www.host.tld/` (i.e. `www` or `public-html` or `htdocs`)
3. Edit `app.php` and adjust the require statements to point to `/home/work/Symfony/app`
4. run `app/console assets:install http://www.host.tld/`

At this point, the app should run from `www.host.tld` assuming your caching permissions are setup correctly.  The routes will have the generated desired paths in them.

No real need to change your web configuration.

Comment: I prefer this answer as I am going to use it (because on shared hosting). But according to the focus of the question (which includes dedicated server) and taking into account, that I personally believe that a proper server config beats individual confiuration, I accepted the other answer. But big thanks here! Exactly the way I was looking for.